# httpclient.postasync - System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, httpclient

I have an upload file function. I upload the file in chunks, it tries to upload a chunk, upon login failure tries to login again and then retries to upload. On some files it works fine and on some not (no consistencies as to which files fail and which upload - same file one time works another not).

the error i get in upload file function:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent'.    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CheckDisposed()    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsync(Stream stream,
>   TransportContext context)    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult
>   ar)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at

The function:

```html
private bool uploadFile(string path, ref string fileName)
        {

            var chunkSize = 1024 * 1024;
            var identifier = Guid.NewGuid();
            using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(path))
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                var count = 1;
                var totalChunkCount = Math.Ceiling((double)fileStream.Length / chunkSize);
                HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                while (fileStream.Position < fileStream.Length)
                {
                    var readCount = fileStream.Length - fileStream.Position > chunkSize
                        ? chunkSize
                        : (int)(fileStream.Length - fileStream.Position);
                    var buffer = new byte[readCount];
                    fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, readCount);
                    using (var chunkedStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                    {
                        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                        {
                            content.Add(new StreamContent(chunkedStream),
                                Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path), Path.GetFileName(path));
                            content.Add(new StringContent(count.ToString()), "ChunkNumber");
                            content.Add(new StringContent(totalChunkCount.ToString()), "TotalChunks");
                            content.Add(new StringContent(identifier), "Identifier");
                            content.Add(new StringContent(Path.GetFileName(path)), "Filename");

                            response = client.PostAsync(m_uploadURL, content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                            {
                                login();
                                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                                response = client.PostAsync(m_uploadURL, content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ShowPercentProgress("Upload of  " + path, count, Convert.ToInt32(totalChunkCount));
                    count++;
                }

                if (response != null)
                {
                    var contents = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    var json = JObject.Parse(contents);
                    var uploadResponse = json.ToObject<UploadResponse>();
                    if (!uploadResponse.status.isSuccess)
                    {
                        Logger.Log("Error: " + uploadResponse.status.statusDescription);
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (uploadResponse.data.allChunksUploaded)
                    {
                        serverFileName = uploadResponse.data.fileName;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Couldn't find an answer on the net

Answer (score 0):

Var content is in braces. And you are using postbasync. So it call asynchronously, when it's out from var scope , content object automatically disposed. 
Try

```
                   var content = new MultipartFormDataContent():

                        content.Add(new StreamContent(chunkedStream),
                            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path), Path.GetFileName(path));
                        content.Add(new StringContent(count.ToString()), "ChunkNumber");
                        content.Add(new StringContent(totalChunkCount.ToString()), "TotalChunks");
                        content.Add(new StringContent(identifier), "Identifier");
                        content.Add(new StringContent(Path.GetFileName(path)), "Filename");
```

Remove using .